# Vs code quick open

Tags: visual-studio-code

VScode's <kbd>⌘-P</kbd> aka quickopen will display current file in the list as well. Is it possible not to display it? I obviously don't want to navigate to the file I'm currently in.

I'm in file `Synchronization.ml`

[image: vscode opened file]

`Synchronization.ml` is in the list on first place, I'd like it not to be there.

[image: quick open]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [#49607](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/49607) was closed as a duplicate of [#30770](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/30770) but it still doesn't hide the active file...

**#49607** is locked => a new issue then: [#64006](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/64006)